# How to use youtube API in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube

My question concerns running script that exists on the page the user is loading. For example on a youtube video if you go to the console and type:

```
player = document.getElementById('movie_player');
```

You can then interact with the player by using :

```
player.getDuration();
```

or

```
player.playVideo();
```

But I searched and researched for a way to do this from a firefox extension and all I could find find was a reference to [XPCNativeWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision) but no real solution.

So let's say I want to get the video duration from the firefox extension, in my main.js code I use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) to detect a youtube video page loading. Then in the contentScriptFile I get the Id of the embeded flash player but I can't interact with it. In fact in extension devolopement console I get an error saying that the function getDuration() does not exists. From what I read on other post this has to do with Xray vision (XPCNativeWrapper).

My problem is I don't know how to use Xray vision to send commands to the content of the webpage I do not own.

PS: I am new to firefox extension programming and it might seem very easy for you but I would really be grateful for any help or lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for asking I found the answer next to my question on the right side panel!
For those who are looking for the same problem :

```
var player = document.getElementById('movie_player').wrappedJSObject;
```

should do the trick.